# What deaths count as "safe" for Hardcore Ironman?

Tags: runescape

The [ironman news post](http://services.runescape.com/m=news/ironman--drop-table-reworks?jptg=ia&jptv=community_news) says

> Note that 'Safe' activities carry no risk of permanent death.

But what exactly does that include? Is it just safe minigames, or are there other "safe" activities?

Answer (score 3):

This is information gathered from the wiki as well as (unfortunate) personal experience.

> **Deaths that do not end hardcore**
>
> Deaths don't end hardcore if they
> are counted as "safe death" in the regular game. Examples include:
>
> - PvP portals near the Fist of Guthix
> - Falling off the pathway in Demon Slayer
> - Dying to Agoroth or a Crassian warrior during A Shadow Over Ashdale
> - Dungeoneering deaths
> - Getting hit with a dragonkin fireball in Missing, Presumed Death
> - Dying in the mansion in Broken Home

Players who choose to activate Hardcore Ironman Mode, in addition, have only one life. As soon as they die, their account is permanently locked, unless they have purchased the ability to convert to a regular Ironman account upon death, namely the [Jar of divine light](https://runescape.wiki/w/Jar_of_divine_light). There is also an option to buy an extra life ([divine coin](https://runescape.wiki/w/Divine_coin)) at total levels 1000 and 1600 for 100,000 and 10,000,000 coins, respectively. This is so that people who have already progressed far into the game are able to avoid losing their accounts from lag, bugs, etc.